# X-Editable - Not showing edit box from ajax response hrefs from modal

Tags: ajax, x-editable

I have a page when you click a button, it opens a Bootrstap 3 modal. This modal's function loads an Ajax call and returns a HTML on a DIV. This HTML has the fields to be used in x-editable. I declared all fields before:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('#Make').editable();   
    $('#Address').editable();    
    ... 
});
```

The Ajax response have all fields previously defined, but don't open the edit box.
Used console log with no errors. Seems it's not calling the function.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

solved my own problem. The element name has space on it. Removed and worked fine.